# Printing a neat looking multiplication table with the format method

Tags: python

This is a question from the book How to Think Like a Computer Scientist, chapter 8. This chapter covers the **format method** in Python.

I have to print out a neat looking multiplication table like this:

[image]

This is the code that I wrote:

```
layout = "{0:>8}{1:>4}{2:>4}{3:>4}{4:>4}{5:>4}{6:>4}" \
         "{7:>4}{8:>4}{9:>5}{10:>5}{11:>5}"

layout2 = "{0:>1}{1:>6}{2:>4}{3:>4}{4:>4}{5:>4}" \
          "{6:>4}{7:>4}{8:>4}{9:>4}{10:>4}{11:>4}{12:>4}"

print(layout.format(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
print(" :-----------------------------------------------------")

for i in range(1, 13):
    print(layout2.format(str(i) + ":", i*1, i*2, i*3, i*4, i*5, i*6,
                         i*7, i*8, i*9, i*10, i*11, i*12))
```

This is what it's printing out:

[image]

Some parts are good, some parts not so good...

[image]

PS: There might be other ways of formatting text on screen so it looks neat and properly aligned, but the chapter is about the format method, so I guess I kinda have to work with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `layout2` only allocates 1 character for the first position, but the largest string you try to fit in it is 3 characters wide.  You should give that field a width of 3 characters:

```
layout = "{0:>8}{1:>4}{2:>4}{3:>4}{4:>4}{5:>4}{6:>4}" \
         "{7:>4}{8:>4}{9:>5}{10:>5}{11:>5}"

layout2 = "{0:>3}{1:>6}{2:>4}{3:>4}{4:>4}{5:>4}" \
          "{6:>4}{7:>4}{8:>4}{9:>4}{10:>4}{11:>4}{12:>4}"

print(layout.format(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
print(" :-----------------------------------------------------")

for i in range(1, 13):
    print(layout2.format(str(i) + ":", i*1, i*2, i*3, i*4, i*5, i*6,
                         i*7, i*8, i*9, i*10, i*11, i*12))
```

prints

```
 1:     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
 2:     2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24
 3:     3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36
 4:     4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48
 5:     5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60
 6:     6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72
 7:     7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84
 8:     8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96
 9:     9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99 108
10:    10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120
11:    11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99 110 121 132
12:    12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96 108 120 132 144
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "ljust" with the maximum number of space you require. lets say 6 digit spaces.

```
'02'.ljust(6)
```

will give

```
"02    "
```

if you want it right aligned use rjust.

Comment: if you find this answer useful please mark this as an accepted answer which will be helpful for future users. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This bypasses the **format method**, but if you wanted a *slightly* more elegant solution you could have `i` as an input and then print any size table

```
i = 14

# padding for i squared
l = len(str(i**2)) + 2
# padding for i
w = len(str(i)) + 2

header = " " * w + " " + "".join([str(j).rjust(l) for j in range(1, i + 1)])
dashes = " " * w + ":" + "-" * l * i
body = "\n".join([str(j).rjust(w) + ":" + "".join([str(j * k).rjust(l) for k in range(1, i+1)]) for j in range(1, i + 1)])

print("\n".join([header, dashes, body]))
```

I used `14` but if you want to see this shine try `34`

```
       1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
  :----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1:    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
 2:    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24   26   28
 3:    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30   33   36   39   42
 4:    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40   44   48   52   56
 5:    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   55   60   65   70
 6:    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60   66   72   78   84
 7:    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70   77   84   91   98
 8:    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80   88   96  104  112
 9:    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90   99  108  117  126
10:   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100  110  120  130  140
11:   11   22   33   44   55   66   77   88   99  110  121  132  143  154
12:   12   24   36   48   60   72   84   96  108  120  132  144  156  168
13:   13   26   39   52   65   78   91  104  117  130  143  156  169  182
14:   14   28   42   56   70   84   98  112  126  140  154  168  182  196
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code which have the same approach as yours.

```
layout = "{0:>4}{1:>4}{2:>4}{3:>4}{4:>4}{5:>4}{6:>4},{7:>4}{8:>4}{9:>5}{10:>5}{11:>5}{12:>5}"
layout1 = "{0:>4}"
print(layout.format("", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
print(layout1.format(":") + "-----------------------------------------------------")
for i in range(1, 13):
    print(layout.format(str(i) + ":", i*1, i*2, i*3, i*4, i*5, i*6, i*7, i*8, i*9, i*10, i*11, i*12))
```